# Big O or Big Omega?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Here's my answers to **Is A O or Ω of B ?** Do you think I got it right?

```
A               B           O   Ω
(log n)^3       N           No  Yes
2n^2+4n         4n^2        Yes No
n!              2^n         No  Yes
n^5             n^4         No  Yes
100             10000       Yes No
n^2             (1.5)^n     No  Yes
```

Comment: Big O represents the _worst_ running time, while Big Omega represents the _best_ running time.

Comment: I think you're wrong about a couple of them. Which ones can you prove?

Comment: I think 1st one should be Yes No because log n is faster than n. Also, last one should be Yes No because n^2 is faster than exponential

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you shouldn't phrase it like this. Big O is an upper bound and big Omega a lower bound for *a given function*. This function can be a best/average/worst case running time of an algorithm, but it needn't be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big O is asymptotically upper bound while Big Omega is asymptotically lower bound.

- A = O(B) if and only if `limit A(n)/B(n) < C` as n approach infinity and C is a positive constant.
- A = Ω(B) if and only if `limit A(n)/B(n) > C > 0` as n approach infinity and C is a positive constant.

You can use [Wolframe Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to find such limit.

```
A               B           O   Ω
(log n)^3       N           Yes  No
2n^2+4n         4n^2        Yes Yes
n!              2^n         No  Yes
n^5             n^4         No  Yes
100             10000       Yes Yes
n^2             (1.5)^n     Yes  No
```

For example:

- [limit n<sup>2</sup>/1.5<sup>n</sup> as n goes to infinite](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n%5E2%2F%281.5%29%5En+as+n-%3Einfinite) is 0. Therefore, we know that 1.5<sup>n</sup> grow faster than `n^2` as n is getting larger and larger. So, 1.5<sup>n</sup> is upper of n<sup>2</sup> but not a lower bound of n<sup>2</sup>.
- [limit (2n^2+4n)/(4n^2) as n goes to infinite](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%282n%5E2%2B4n%29%2F%284n%5E2%29+as+n-%3Einfinite) is 0.5.

  - We could say that `limit A(n)/B(n) < 1`. Therefore, A = O(B).
  - We could say that `limit A(n)/B(n) > 0.4 > 0`. Therefore, A = Ω(B).

Comment: The definitions of big O and big Theta aren't correct. f(n) = (n if n is odd, 2n if n is even) is O(n), but limit f(n)/n doesn't exist.

Comment: @PaulHankin, But we could say that limit f(n)/n = 1 if n goes to odd infinity and limit f(n)/n = 2 if n goes to even infinity. Therefore, limit f(n)/n <= 2 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @invisal Maybe you meant to use "limsup" and "liminf"?

Comment: @PaulHankin, I think the definition is correct. In "Introduction to Algorithm" state that O(g(n)) = {f(n): there exists positive constants C and m such that 0 <= f(n) <= Cg(n) for all n > m}. Let twist the definition a bit. 0 <= f(n)/g(n) <= C (divide all side by g(n)). Let m be as large as possible, therefore we have 0 <= limit f(n)/g(n) <= C as n goes to infinity.

Comment: In Concrete Mathematics also use limit to define "tilde notation" such that limit f(n)/g(n) = 1 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @invisal I see what you mean, but you're using "limit" differently from its very standard use in mathematics. A mathematician (and also the authors of "Introduction to Algorithms") would not accept that 0 < f(n) < C implies limit f(n) <= C as n -> infinity, because they would say that the limit may not exist.